# Javascript Module Pattern and jquery Ajax wait issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wait, module-pattern

I have written a custom js module that basically sends messages and needs to wait for a response in order to continue:

```
var manageBooking = (function (jQ) {

//decalre private variables
var domain, msgRecieved, msgResponse, validationValue;
//decalre private functions
var sendMessage, wait;

// A private variables
domain = document.domain;
msgRecieved = false;
msgResponse = null;


wait = function(timeOutStep){
    var w;
    console.log('msgRecieved', msgRecieved);
    if (msgRecieved === true) {
        clearTimeout(w);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('waiting..');
        w = setTimeout(wait, timeOutStep, timeOutStep);
    }
}

// A private function to send messages
sendMessage = function( requestURL, data, type ) {
    console.log(requestURL);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(type);
    //reset vars to defaults
    msgRecieved = false;
    msgResponse = null;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://"+domain+"/_ajax/"+requestURL,
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        data: data,
        type: type,
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            msgResponse = msg;
            msgRecieved = true;
        }
    });
    console.log('after ajax call');
    wait(500);
    console.log('after wait');
    console.log('msgRecieved', msgRecieved);
    return;
};
return {

// A public variable
errorMsg: "",
validationName: "",
bookingID: "",
output: "",
// A public function to login
login: function( enteredBookingID, enteredSurname ) {
    // Call private sendMsg
    sendMessage("user_login/"+enteredBookingID+"/"+enteredSurname, null, 'GET');
    console.log(msgResponse);
    throw "error";
    //check response
    var patt=/Sorry/i;
    //test pattern
    var result=patt.test($.trim(msgResponse));
    //if false OK
    if (result === false) {
        var split = msgResponse.split('|');
        validationName = split[0];
        validationValue = split[1];
        bookingID = enteredBookingID
        return true;
    }
    //else error
    errorMsg = msgResponse;
    return false;
}
};
})(jQuery);
manageBooking.login(123,123);
```

The issue i am having is forcing the `sendMessage` function to wait until the ajax completes and sets `msgRecieved` to true.

However it appears that the `sendMessage` function hits the `wait` function once and then continues.
the following console output shows the order of events:

```
GET http://website/_ajax/user_login/123/123
after ajax call //sendMessage()
msgRecieved, false //wait()
waiting.. //wait()
after wait //sendMessage()
msgRecieved, false //sendMessage()
null//login()
uncaught exception: error //login() 
<p>Sorry, we cannot locate your details.  </p> <!-- jQuery Ajax call -->
msgRecieved, true //wait()
```

What I am confused with is that the `wait` function seems to fire again right at the end..

can anyone give me some pointers on getting this to work?

Comment: Use callbacks instead of fighting against the way JavaScript is intended to be programmed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript behaves in an asynchronous manner, meaning it **does not wait**.

You have a part in your code that looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://"+domain+"/_ajax/"+requestURL,
    dataType: "html",
    async: true,
    data: data,
    type: type,
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        msgResponse = msg;
        msgRecieved = true;
    }
});
```

You should place the code to be run when the response arrives within the `success` function, like so:

```
success : function (msg) {
    handleMessage(msg); // Or any other manipulation to the received message
}

function handleMessage(msg) {
    // Work with your received message here.
}
```

`success` will be called with the *received* message, it is a callback.

The right way to implement `sendMessage` would be the following way:

```
sendMessage = function( requestURL, data, type, callback ) {
    console.log(requestURL);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(type);
    //reset vars to defaults
    msgRecieved = false;
    msgResponse = null;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://"+domain+"/_ajax/"+requestURL,
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        data: data,
        type: type,
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            msgResponse = msg;
            msgRecieved = true;
            // Call the callback function to notify the message
            // was received
            callback();
        }
    });
};
```

and then using it like so:

```
sendMessage(urlHere, dataHere, typeHere, function () {
    // Message has been received, msgResponse and msgReceived
    // have already been updated. Do what you need here
});
```

Comment: HI Thanks, I know it does not wait - im trying to force it. the reason being is so that i only have 1 ajax call on the page and other functions use that rather than having to define a new ajax call for each function - eg not repeting code.

Comment: <strike>further to this i have gotten js to work like the above in the global scope - but im trying to do this in `manageBooking` scope</strike> scrap that it was inside the jquery.ajax success function..

Comment: I see. Well, there is really no need for this in JavaScript, you could keep the Event-loop busy if you like (something like `while(timePassed < 500) {}` but it's just going to consume resources instead of idling. There is no way to natively make JavaScript wait in idle state.

Comment: agreed. no native way but surely the `setInterval()` or `setTimeOut` functions should halt execution until the variable is set to true?

Comment: setTimeout works this way: `setTimeout(function () { /* Callback code to execute */ }, 1000);`, will execute the specified function after a second. Even setTimeout does not wait, it just schedules execution later and processing continues.

Comment: accepting this answer as the call back function is how it should be done (and thanks for the example - finally got my head around callbacks!) just re fracturing my code to cater for this :)

Comment: Happy to hear that, keep me posted :)

Comment: @ScottJones You can name the callback function instead of using an anonymous one: `function responseArrived() { /* handle responses */ } sendMessage(url,data,type,responseArrived);` and then you can test `responseArrived`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the JavaScript setInterval function instead of setTimeout. But this time, break up sendMessage, and place the part that needs to execute after the ajax message is received under a setInterval.

Once the ajax message is received this second part of sendMessage runs (after messagereceived is true), and also clears the interval.

This is since setTimeout() only executes once after a set interval.

setInterval() executes repeatedly exery interval until it is cleared.

More information can be found [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be related to the scope of your `w` variable, because on second call (in the wait function, into your `else` branch) you're destroying the reference to the timeout you previously created, so the clearTimeout can't work: try to define it in the immediate outer scope.

Comment: this did indeed allow it to loop as i expected but it still only did this after the code continued back to the `login` function..